# Why do I need more quota in Google Developers Console when I only have 7 projects?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have 7 projects in Google Developers Console. Of those, only two are deployed to app engine. One version each. These two projects hardly consume any resources.

I tried to create one more project and I got this error message:

[image]

Their documentation states that the limit is 25 projects per account. 
So, somebody know why? And what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*App Engine FAQ: Each account can host 25 free applications*

submit a new request to increase the project limit and it will ne granted. It seems, it would be a kind of new order - [read this reddit topic](https://goo.gl/H3dGyx).